# Is it safe practice to edit a list while looping through it?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop

I was trying to execute a for loop like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(0, len(a), 1):
    if a[i] == 4:
        a.remove(a[i])
```

I end up having an `index error` since the `length` of the list becomes shorter but the iterator `i` does not become aware.

So, my question is, how can something like that be coded? Can the `range` of `i` be updated in each iterations of the loop based on current array condition?

Comment: If the length keeps changing, the loop will be quite unpredictable. Where will it stop?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You'd get stuck in an infinite loop if the length was dynamically calculated in the `range` function.

Comment: even if this loop of yours did work, it would run forever.

Comment: But what if a user want to pop an element from array in mid of loop and he want to go to till end of the loopf?

Comment: @syam That is a bad design pattern. Your data structures should remain immutable to allow for correctness checking of the code.

Comment: @syam This kind of thing depends vastly on what the goal of the program is.

Comment: @syam There are tricks for that but it is not advisable. The `index` gets messed up. If you really have to do this this way, consider entering the list from the back. But not for your example. This simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to tell us about your desired behavior with the code.

Comment: It is better practice to create a new list in this case rather than alter the current one mid-loop

Answer (score 2):

For the `.pop()` that you mention for example you can use a list comprehension to create a second list or even modify the original one in place. Like so:

```
alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2]

alist = [x for x in alist if x != 4]
print(alist)
#[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2]
```

As **user2393256** more generally puts it, you can generalize and define a function `my_filter()` which will return a `boolean` based on some check you implement in it. And then you can do:

```
def my_filter(a_value):
    return True if a_value != 4 else False

alist = [x for x in alist if my_filter(x)]
```

I would go with the function solution if the check was too complicated to type in the list comprehension, so mainly for readability. The example above is therefore not the best since the check is very simple but i just wanted to show you how it would be done.

Comment: Someone should edit the original question in order to reflect what it truly asks. Right now this seems like a completely off answer unless someone reads the comment.

Comment: @Jim i do not know to what extend one can modify a question but i am pretty sure i stretched it. Let's see..

Comment: Okay, I've accepted the edit after making some improvements. If anyone thinks this is a stretch, a roll-back can be made.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete elements from your list while iterating over it you should use list comprehension.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = [x for x in a if not check(x)]
```

You would need to write a "check" function that returns wether or not you want to keep the element in the list.

Comment: Thanks, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are going with that but this would do what I beleive you want :

```
i=0
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
while boolean_should_i_stop_the_loop :
   if i>=len(a) :
      boolean_should_i_stop_the_loop = False
   #here goes what you want to do in the for loop
   print i;
   a.append(4)
   i += 1
```